# Is std::views::keys guaranteed to work correctly with any pair/tuple type?

Tags: c++, c++20, std-ranges

Code is pasted here & https://www.godbolt.org/z/qszqYsT4o

I am attempting to provide `boost::adaptors::indexed` functionality that is compatible with c++20 views.  My primary use case is for `std::vector`, but I would definitely prefer a generic solution.  I was shocked to discover that `std::views::keys` did not work as expected to extract the first element correctly.

For GCC 10.3, the output of `rng1` is garbage and `rng2` is as expected.  GCC 10.4+ works fine.
The latest version of clang fails to compile the code.

Questions:

1. Is `std::views::keys` guaranteed to support any pair/tuple type, or is my code UB?
2. Given clang 14.0.0 fails to compile, is my code legal C++?
3. Is there a better way to achieve this functionality in c++20?  I was looking at `std::span` for a bit, but couldn't seem to make it work naturally.  Note: I would have gladly used `std::views::zip` with `std::views::iota` if it were available.

```
#include <vector>
#include <ranges>
#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
using IndexValuePair = std::pair<std::size_t, std::reference_wrapper<T>>;

template <typename T, typename Allocator>
auto make_indexed_view(std::vector<T, Allocator>& vec)
{
    auto fn = [&vec](T& val) {
        return IndexValuePair<T>{static_cast<std::size_t>(&val - vec.data()), val};
    };
    return std::views::all(vec) | std::views::transform(fn);
}

template <typename T, typename Allocator>
auto make_indexed_view(const std::vector<T, Allocator>& vec)
{
    auto fn = [&vec](const T& val) {
        return IndexValuePair<const T>{static_cast<std::size_t>(&val - vec.data()), val};
    };
    return std::views::all(vec) | std::views::transform(fn);
}

struct GetFirstSafely {
    template <typename T1, typename T2>
    const T1& operator()(const std::pair<T1, T2>& p) const { return std::get<0>(p); }

    template <typename T1, typename T2>
    T1 operator()(std::pair<T1, T2>&& p) const { return std::get<0>(std::move(p)); }
};

auto get_first = [](auto&& p) -> decltype(auto) { return GetFirstSafely{}(std::forward<decltype(p)>(p)); };

int main()
{
    const std::vector<int> v{10, 20, 30};
    auto fn = [](const auto& val) { return val.second >= 20; };
    auto rng1 = make_indexed_view(v) | std::views::filter(fn) | std::views::keys;
    auto rng2 = make_indexed_view(v) | std::views::filter(fn) | std::views::transform(get_first);
    for (auto&& elem : rng1)
        std::cout << elem << '\n';
    for (auto&& elem : rng2)
        std::cout << elem << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The Clang errors are probably just due to a known Clang bug that makes libstdc++'s implementation of views not work with it, see https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/issues/52696 and https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/issues/44178.

Comment: In fact, I think clang-trunk already supports C++20 `<ranges>` with `-stdlib=libc++`, but I don't know why the [Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/r66zGfM3W) is giving a `no member named 'views' in namespace 'std'` error *recently*, I remember it was working fine a few weeks ago.

Comment: @康桓瑋 It seems to be guarded behind the flag `-fexperimental-library`. But even with it `std::views::keys` seems to still be missing: https://godbolt.org/z/zxnhee3nz

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was [LWG 3502](https://cplusplus.github.io/LWG/issue3502). Your code fails on gcc 10.3 because of that particular issue, but it has been resolved and your code works fine on gcc 10.4 (or 11.1, etc.).

The example in the issue there should look familiar:

```cpp
std::vector<int> vec = {42};
auto r = vec | std::views::transform([](auto c) { return std::make_tuple(c, c); })
             | std::views::keys;
```

It failed because `operator*` for `elements_view` was specified as:

```cpp
constexpr decltype(auto) operator*() const { return get<N>(*current_); }
```

And when the `N`th element is a prvalue (as it is in that example and your example), this is an immediately-dangling rvalue reference. The resolution in the issue ensures that `operator*` in these cases returns a prvalue, so everything works fine.

---

Note that there's no reason to write:

```cpp
return std::views::all(vec) | std::views::transform(fn);
```

The range adaptors already do that for you. You can just write:

```cpp
return vec | std::views::transform(fn);
```

Answer (score 5):

> Is `std::views::keys` guaranteed to support any pair/tuple type, or is
> my code UB?

`views::keys` is guaranteed to work with `pair`/`tuple` in C++20, and is guaranteed to work with *`tuple-like`* objects in C++23 thanks to [P2165](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2022/p2165r4.pdf).

> Given clang 14.0.0 fails to compile, is my code legal C++?

Your code is well-formed.

However, it is not necessary to use `reference_wrapper`, a simple `pair<size_t, T&>` should be enough, and there is no need to use `std::views::all(vec)`, `vec | views::transform(fn)` will automatically convert `vec` to `view`.

> Is there a better way to achieve this functionality in c++20?

In C++20, I'm afraid not. In C++23 you can use [`views::enumerate`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges/enumerate_view):

```
const std::vector<int> v{10, 20, 30};
for (const auto& [index, value] : v | views::enumerate)
  std::cout << index << " " << value << "\n";
```

Comment: just to confirm, this means there is a defect in GCC 10.3, correct?

Comment: @MarkB Yep, that's a defect in the standard. Barry already answered it for me, see [his great answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73178262/11638718).

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to use `std::span` for `make_indexed_view` to make it more generic.
Of course, modifying the structure of the underlying sequence (e.g. calling `std::vector::push_back`) is undefined behavior.

```
template <typename T, std::size_t Extent>
auto make_indexed_view(const std::span<T, Extent>& span)
{
    auto fn = [span](T& val) {
        return IndexValuePair<T>{static_cast<std::size_t>(&val - span.data()), val};
    };
    return span | std::views::transform(fn);    
}

int main()
{
    constexpr int data[] = {10, 20, 30};
    auto fn = [](const auto& elem) { return elem.second >= 20; };
    auto rng = make_indexed_view(std::span{data}) | std::views::filter(fn) | std::views::transform(get_first);
    for (auto&& elem : rng) {
        std::cout << elem << '\n';
    }
    return 0;
}
```